# Align checkbox to the right on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, checkbox, horizontalfieldmanager

I need to align a CheckboxField to the right of a fixed text (on Blackberry) like the "manage connections" dialog.
The code is:

```
final HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
hfm.add(new LabelField("Test me please", LabelField.ELLIPSIS | FIELD_LEFT | FIELD_VCENTER | USE_ALL_WIDTH));
cbx = new CheckboxField(null, false, FIELD_RIGHT | CheckboxField.NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH);
hfm.add(cbx);
```

I tried various combinations of "USE_ALL_WIDTH", "NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH" and similar flags, but I still can't get what I want: text all the way to the left, and check box all the way to the right.
If the label is set to USE_ALL_WIDTH, the checkbox disappears, and if it's not set, the checkbox is displayed near the text (not on the right side of the hfm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code,this will solve your problem.

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
LabelField lblShow = new LabelField("Test me please ", Field.FIELD_LEFT);
CheckboxField cbShow = new CheckboxField("", false, CheckboxField.FIELD_RIGHT );
VerticalFieldManager vfmLeft = new VerticalFieldManager();
VerticalFieldManager vfmRight = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH); 
vfmLeft.add(lblShow);
vfmRight.add(cbShow);       
hfm.add(vfmLeft);
hfm.add(vfmRight);
add(hfm);
```

Comment: Found a better solution: draw the whold checkbox on a bitmap, and then cut the bitmap in two and render it on the canvas flipping left and right part.

Comment: The `vfmLeft` is redundant here. You could get away with adding the label directly to the horizontal field manager, i.e. `hfm.add(lblShow)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use This style bit to align checkbox to right.

```
private static final long checkBoxStyle = 134217728;

add(new CheckboxField("test " , false, checkBoxStyle | USE_ALL_WIDTH));
```

Comment: By the way, that value is just 0x8000000 (i.e. set leftmost bit)

Comment: This is just the `CheckboxField.NO_USE_ALL_WIDTH` value, available from BlackBerry API 7.0.0 - it will not work on earlier devices.